# protect " for a request

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a sql request like this:

```
"INSERT INTO pirate(title, title_simple, user, magnet_link, \
 url, created, size, infos, images, description, number, response, new) VALUES
 (\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\", \
  \"{4}\", \"{5}\", \"{6}\", \"{7}\", \"{8}\", \"{9}\", \"{10}\", \"{11}\", \"{12}\")".format(blablabla...)
```

But some of the parameters of my query are huge pieces of text, mostly like a description. And sometimes there is this character in the text: `"`

I already tried to protect the strings I use in my query, with this syntax for an example:

```
\"{9}\"
```

But it does not work for `"`. Do you have any idea about how to solve my basic problem, and what is the good way to do it ?

EDIT:

@Martijn Pieters: I tried but it does not work:

```
requete = "INSERT INTO pirate(title, title_simple, user, magnet_link, \
           url, created, size, infos, images, description, number, response, new) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

params = (torrent.title, simpleChar(torrent.title), torrent.user, torrent.magnet_link,
      str(torrent.url), torrent.created, strByteToOctet(torrent.size)[1],
      str_infos, str_images, torrent.info, torrent.id, retours, True)

bdd = sqlite3.connect("fichiers.sqlite")
bdd.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
c = bdd.cursor()

c.execute(requete, params)

bdd.commit()
c.close()
bdd.close()
```

Also, I'm doing this in a thread, so I don't get easily debug infos

Comment: "I'm doing this in a thread, so I don't get easily debug infos". Well, do it *not* in a thread to debug it, before you do it in a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave escaping of values **to the database adapter**. Use SQL parameters instead, **not** string formatting:

```
query = """\
    INSERT INTO pirate(
        title, title_simple, user, magnet_link,
        url, created, size, infos, images, description, number, response, new) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """

params = (pirate_title, simplify(pirate_title), userid, link, url,
          datetime.now(), 0, torrent_infos, torrent_images, desc,
          42, response, True)
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Using SQL parameters delegates escaping to the specialist, preventing SQL injection attacks and allowing the database to cache and reuse any query plans it generates.

See the [`sqlite3` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or :1.)

Comment: And what is params in this case ?

Comment: @user1585507: a sequence of your `blablablabla` part in your string formatting. The values to be inserted in the same order as the `?` placeholders.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't understand why what I've written doesn't work, it's basically the same as yours

Comment: No, I'm in a thread and I don't get any feedback. I don't know how to get the errors, but I'm pretty sure the request written like that is crashing. It's working with my crappy syntax (except if the strings contain ")

Comment: @user1585507: and your crappy syntax is wide open for SQL injection attacks. Use a logger and log exceptions.

Comment: @user1585507: test your code without threads with dummy data first, I'd say.

Comment: @user1585507: in any case, I tested with a dummy set of data for your `params` tuple, and otherwise used your exact syntax, and the insertion works just fine.

Comment: Okay I figured it out (I think), I used a dummy set of data out of my thread, and the variable torrent.created returned by the API I use is a datetime object, so there is this in my query: datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 25, 18, 6, 30, 882795), 8128225608